# Should I change the localhost to be my public IP DNS address inside Nginx server config file?

Tags: amazon-ec2, nginx-config

My front-end in running on port 3000 and my back-end on port 8000.
I've deployed my app using EC2 instance and I've installed Nginx and PM2.
When I try to open the app on the browser using my public DNS address the app appears for a short period of time then it breaks. It shows me the error

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

> GET http://localhost:8000/api/info/countByType net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here is where my front-end is making the request

```
 export const countByCity = createAsyncThunk("info/countByCity", async() => {
    try{
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/info/countByCity");
        return res.data;
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error.response)
    }
});
```

and here is my */etc/nginx/sites-available/default* file configuration

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/booking.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
       proxy_pass http://ec2-54-167-89-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

}
```

I have changed the proxy_pass to be my Public IP address. The previous configuration was http://localhost:8000.

My question is : My front end is trying to reach the localhost:8000 endpoint. Should I change it to be my Public DNS address instead? Example :   http://ec2-54-167-89-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/info/countByCity ?

Answer (score 1):

This code in your front end is running in the user's web browser, **not** on the EC2 server:

```
 const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/info/countByCity");
```

When that code tries to access `localhost` it is trying to access a server running on your local laptop/PC, not a server in AWS. You need to change that `localhost` address to be the public IP of your EC2 server.

---

This proxy configuration on your Nginx server:

`proxy_pass http://ec2-54-167-89-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000;`

Is going all the way out to the Internet and back, just to access a service that is running on a different port of the same server. You need to change that to be `localhost` for both security and efficiency.